# Can I close or disable ports without iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, port

I need to disable or close a couple of ports on a  RHEL 5.3 Redhat server, without using IPtables .IPtables is already switched off (disabled)on this system.Is there any alternative way of closing or disabling these ports either via command line or via changes in configuration files .

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you change a service so that it listens to an internal IP, then that port on the public interface will be "disabled".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually close the port a daemon is listening on you will have to disable the daemon or make it listen on the loopback interface.

Since most daemons are not of any use if they are not serving any clients i would start by disabling everything you don't actually need.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, simply disable any services you don't need first. The commands `service` and `chkconfig` on RHEL can help you determine what is running, stop services and disable them at boot time.

Then, use tcpwrappers where possible to restrict access to various services that need to run for a particular set of clients but should be denied to everyone else.

http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2005/10/using-tcp-wrappers-to-secure-linux.html

Comment: Many Thanks for your help , i really appreciate this